# jQuery form + Spring - send a ModelAtribute

Tags: java, jquery, spring

I would like to send form data with jQuery to a Spring Boot Controller, because i need them to be validated, but i cannot understand how to pass objects.

I have this object to be validated

```
public class ReservationConfirmDTO {

private long reservationId;

    private Vehicle vehicle;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)

    @NotNull
    private Date fromDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)

    private Date toDate;


    @JsonView(Views.FewDetails.MediumDetails.class)
    private Address startAddress;

    @JsonView(Views.FewDetails.MediumDetails.class)
    private Address endAddress;


    private VehicleBrand brand;


    private List<Service> services;
//getters and setters
```

And in my controller i have this kind of controller

```
@PostMapping("/save")
    public @ResponseBody String saveAdminReservation(@Valid @ModelAttribute("reservation") ReservationConfirmDTO wrapper, @RequestParam long userId, @RequestParam(required=false) String list,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, ModelMap model, WebRequest request) {
//logic inside
    }
```

So, in my view i try to build a `reservation` object

```
reservation.vehicle = response.vehicle; //from a previous POST response
reservation.fromDate = $('#fromDate').val();
reservation.toDate = $('#toDate').val();
var startAddress = {addressId: $('#startAddressSelector option:selected').val()};
var endAddress = {
                addressId: $('#endAddressSelector option:selected').val()
        }
var brand = {
                brandId : $('#brandSelector option:selected').val()
        }

reservation.startAddress = startAddress;
reservation.endAddress = endAddress;
reservation.brand = brand;
```

In this way i have, for instance a StartAddress which has only addressId field

Then, i try to pass this reservation to the controller

```
$('#requestForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/reservation/save',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data:reservation,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response)
            },
            failure: function (response){
                console.log(response)
            }
        })
    })
```

but i get a 500 error

Invalid property 'brand[brandId]' of bean class `[it.besmart.eshare.dto.ReservationConfirmDTO]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'brand[brandId]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [VehicleBrand [brandId=0, brandName=null, description=null]]`

This happens also for startAddress and EndAddress

VehicleBrand is

```
public class VehicleBrand {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long brandId;

    private String brandName;

    private String description;

//getters and setters
    }
```

Comment: Springboot is trying to serialize the payload into a ReservationConfirmDTO object but was unable to find the attribute brand.brandId.  Share the code of VehicleBrand bean.

Comment: You could use browser’s developer tools and check what the json payload sent to the server.

Comment: And I just noticed, you need to Stringify the json object before sending out(as the answer shows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to stringify the JsonObject

```
$('#requestForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/reservation/save',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(reservation),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
        },
        failure: function (response){
            console.log(response)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: this is correct, if you add also that i should remove @ModelAttribute from the controller i can accept it

Comment: No problem, that's my answer and probably will help anyone else.  Best!